# Can't mass assign protected attributes - it's mass assigning fields in attr_accessor

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, mass-assignment, attr-accessor

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_confirmation

---

Both of those fields are not mapped in the database, they are just fields in the form that I want to use to enable some nice validations.

Here is my model class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password_hash, :password_salt
  attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates :password, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

I was under the impression that by placing `password` and `password_confirmation` in the attr_accessor method they would **not** be mass assigned, yet here I am with this little issue.

Any suggestions?

Here's my migration field so you can see what fields are actually in my database.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_hash
      t.string :password_salt

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**attr_accessible** specifies a white list of model attributes that can be set via mass-assignment.
**attr_accessor** creating an instance variable (@name) and a corresponding access method to read it. Also creates a method called name= to set the attribute.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates :email, presence: true

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **:password_confirmation** and **:password**  in **attr_accessible**